# Delphi custom component not scaling correctly with UI DPI scaling

Tags: delphi, components, dpi

I have a really simple custom component, a `TPanel` descendant with a `TLabel`, `TComboBox` and 2 `TButton`s, which appear completely fine when no UI DPI scaling is active.

[image]

```
  TSledgeProcessEditorPresets = class (TPanel)
  private
    FSledgeProcessEditor: TSledgeProcessEditor;
    FPresetOptions: TSledgeProcessEditorPresetOptions;
    FOnPresetSave: TSledgeProcessEditorPresetsSaveEvent;
    procedure SetSledgeProcessEditor(Value: TSledgeProcessEditor);
    procedure ButtonSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBoxPresetsSelect(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
    procedure Loaded; override;
  public
    Presets: TList<TPresetInfo>;
    LabelPresets: TLabel;
    ComboBoxPresets: TComboBox;
    ButtonSave: TButton;
    ButtonDelete: TButton;
    Constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    Destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Clear;
    procedure LoadPresets;
    function Add(PresetInfo: TPresetInfo): Boolean;
    function Delete(Index: Integer): Boolean;
    function Select(Index: Integer): Boolean; overload;
    function Select(Name: String): Boolean; overload;
  published
    property SledgeProcessEditor: TSledgeProcessEditor read FSledgeProcessEditor write SetSledgeProcessEditor;
    property PresetOptions: TSledgeProcessEditorPresetOptions read FPresetOptions write FPresetOptions;
    property OnPresetSave: TSledgeProcessEditorPresetsSaveEvent read FOnPresetSave write FOnPresetSave;
  end;
```

With 125% scaling, the component appears truncated:

[image]

If the form's `Scaled` property is set to False, it appears correctly.
It also appears correctly if `Scaled` is False and I manually call `ScaleBy()` for the form in its `OnCreate` event.

It seems that, after many tries, that the component's eg. `TComboBox`'s width is appearing scaled from the components's `Create()` values and not from the designed/resized size.

The `TPanel`'s width appearing is correct +25%, but the content's sizes are not taken from the designed size but from the `Create()` values.

Comment: Until just a few major versions ago, Delphi did not support DPI scaling at all. Now it does, and with each new release its DPI support gets a little better, but it is still quite broken in places. So you may be best off continuing to use your own scaling and not rely on Delphi's scaling, until Embarcadero gets it working 100%.

Comment: Ok, solved it with an OnResize() event, reposition and resize the controls from it. Thank you!